# How to disable the replica set monitor output

Tags: mongodb

I have a bash script which tries to monitor the number of documents in a collection by connecting to a replica set.

```
COUNT=`/bin/mongo --quiet --host $REPLICA_SET policy -u myuser -p mypwd --eval 'db.myColl.count()'`
```

I was expecting only a number as output, however I got:

```
Mon Apr 27 13:33:57.716 starting new replica set monitor for replica set xx wit                                                                             h seed of xxx 
Mon Apr 27 13:33:57.719 succes                                                                             sfully connected to seed xx for replica set xx
Mon Apr 27 13:33:57.719 changing hosts to ...  

...

Mon Apr 27 13:33:57.736 [ReplicaSetMonitorWatcher] starting 3043
```

Could anyone tell me how to disable this bunch of output? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I could not figure how to disable this. As a workaround you could a) `tail -1` your output, or b) output a token that's likely to be unique just before your output and then `grep` it (e.g. in js: `print("__myAwesomeOutput__=" + x + ";")`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot right now: this is a known bug in the mongo shell: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-27159

That bug proposes some workarounds, none of which are completely satisfactory.